# SQL SERVER add Check constraint for 2 Colmuns two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, alter

Hello I want to add a check constraint for a table but I want to compare a two columns from different tables

```
ALTER TABLE Installation 
ADD Constraint chk_1 check (DateInstallation < dateachat)
```

DateInstallation is a column for the table Installation and dateachat is from  another table named Support, So how to do that knownig that the code give me an error and thank's

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a simple `check` constraint.  You basically have two options:

1. Use triggers.  This requires `insert` and `update` triggers on `installation`.
2. Write a UDF to extract the corresponding value from the other table and use that.

With the UDF, the constraint would look something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Installation ADD Constraint chk_1 
    CHECK (DateInstallation < dbo.get_dateachat(installationId));
```

With either of these solutions, you may need a constraint on the *second* table in case `dateachat` changes.  Triggers and check constraints won't be evaluated based on changes in the *second* table.

Answer (score 1):

And which dateachat would you want to compare to ?  given that it "is from another table", that therefore there might be >1 row, ergo there might be >1 dateachat value to compare to.

The onus is on you to specify that in your expression, e.g.

ADD Constraint chk_1 check (DateInstallation < (SELECT dateachat FROM Support WHERE ...)).

CHECK constraints of this nature are indeed valid constraints in standard SQL, but you will not find any actual product that supports/accepts them, because the SELECT FROM now makes it clear that this is a multi-table constraint.  The evaluation scope accepted by the typical SQL DBMS for CHECK constraints is one single tuple (/row).

(As an additional aside, CHECK constraints define expressions that must be ***satisfied*** by the proposed tuples(/rows).  Meaning your case seems to suggest that installation date must be ***prior*** to purchase date, which may seem weird.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of questions that you need to ask yourself here and possibly ways to approach this.

1. You could do something along these lines with UPDATE or INSERT TRIGGERS.
2. Your constraint definition is a bit odd to begin with - how are you planning to associate a row in table Installation with a row in table Support to get 'dateachat'?
3. There is a (probably strong) argument that what you have here is business logic and should not be replicated as a constraint in the database but instead enforced in application logic.  It also raises some questions about your database structure - is there possibly a better way to design your tables to avoid having a constraint like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a scalar function. 
Put the logic in the function and then CHECK (condition "involving function and table columns" is true)

Rule of thumb, try to use functions which return preferably a true or false (0, 1).
Play it safe, and always check for null in the check constraint definition CHECK(ISNULL(function, 0) = 1). Try not to abuse checks with functions, if the function starts performing aggregates (counting existing rows etc) then it might be time to reconsider the approach for data integrity, keep it simple.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Purchase
(
PurchaseId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Description VARCHAR(10),
PurchaseDate DATE
);

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Installation
(
InstallationId INT IDENTITY,
InstallationDate DATE,
InstallationPurchaseId INT NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CheckIfPurchaseIsBeforeDate(@PurchaseId INT, @Date DATE)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(1), 0) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Purchase WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId AND PurchaseDate < @Date));
END
GO

--ALTER TABLE dbo.Installation DROP CONSTRAINT chkInstallationDate; 
ALTER TABLE dbo.Installation ADD CONSTRAINT chkInstallationDate CHECK(ISNULL(dbo.CheckIfPurchaseIsBeforeDate(InstallationPurchaseId, InstallationDate), 0) = 1);
GO

--two orders
INSERT INTO dbo.Purchase(Description, PurchaseDate)
VALUES('November', '20191110'), ('December', '20191206');
GO

--install the order of november2019 in  january 2020
INSERT INTO dbo.Installation(InstallationDate, InstallationPurchaseId)
VALUES('20200115', 1);
GO

--install the order of december2019 in october2019
INSERT INTO dbo.Installation(InstallationDate, InstallationPurchaseId)
VALUES('20191020', 2); --check constraint conflict
GO

--set the installation of november2019 back to october
UPDATE dbo.Installation
SET InstallationDate = '20201010'
WHERE InstallationId = 1; --check constraint conflict
GO
```